Save Contact with vcf works on mac, but not on iPhone
I have some code to save contact info as a vcf. The code works fine, but when using on iOS the contact never saves. It only works on Mac. Not sure if there is something I am missing or what. I tried a couple libraries and got the same result.
Do not read. The warning said I do not have enough details and there is literally nothing else for me to add that is not a waste of time. Blah blah blah. Hello. Is this enough details?
Here is the code:
  const generateVCFHandler = async (
    name: string,
    avatar: string,
    links: Link[],
  ) => {
    let vCardString = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\n";

    // Name and formatted name
    const names = name.split(" ");
    const firstName = names[0];
    const lastName = names.length > 1 ? names[names.length - 1] : "";
    vCardString += `FN:${name}\nN:${lastName};${firstName};;;\n`;

    // Add avatar
    if (avatar) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `/api/fetchImage?url=${encodeURIComponent(avatar)}`,
        );
        const { base64, mimeType } = await response.json();
        if (base64 && mimeType) {
          vCardString += `PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=${mimeType.split("/")[1]}:${base64}\n`;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch image base64", error);
      }
    }

    // Iterate over links to add relevant contact information
    links.forEach((link) => {
      switch (link.icon) {
        case "CiPhone":
          vCardString += `TEL;TYPE=CELL:${link.url.replace("tel:", "")}\n`;
          break;
        case "CiMail":
          vCardString += `EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:${link.url.replace("mailto:", "")}\n`;
          break;
        case "CiFacebook":
          vCardString += `URL;TYPE=Facebook:${link.url}\n`;
          break;
        case "CiInstagram":
          vCardString += `URL;TYPE=Instagram:${link.url}\n`;
          break;
        case "CiLinkedin":
          vCardString += `URL;TYPE=LinkedIn:${link.url}\n`;
          break;
        case "BsTwitterX":
          vCardString += `URL;TYPE=X:${link.url}\n`;
          break;
      }
    });

    vCardString += "END:VCARD";

    // Download the vCard
    const blob = new Blob([vCardString], { type: "text/vcard;charset=utf-8;" });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "contact.vcf";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  };

Here is an example output:
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:Bob User
N:User;Man;;;
TEL;TYPE=CELL:1 (123) 222-3333
URL;TYPE=Facebook:https://facebook.com/myprofile
URL;TYPE=Instagram:https://instagram.com/haha
END:VCARD


Where do you expect it to save? And please provide a runnable snippet

Here is a link to the code in production.
https://profiles.gettapp3d.com/jon
